# Difference between "is not null" and "<> Null" in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Could you help me, I need to understand about the difference between

```
select * from table where field <> NULL;
```

and

```
select * from table where field is not NULL;
```

and see

```
SELECT COUNT(*) where (1 = null) -- return 0
SELECT COUNT(*) where (1 <> null) -- return 0
SELECT COUNT(*) where (1 is not  null) -- return 1
SELECT COUNT(*) where (null = null) -- return 0
SELECT COUNT(*) where (null <> null) -- return 0
SELECT COUNT(*) where (null is null) -- return 1
SELECT COUNT(*) where (null is not  null) -- return 0
```

Why is `null = null` false?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Short answer: **Comparison operators with `NULL` always produce `NULL`. Period.**

Comment: thanks @lad2025 , but why (null = null) is false?

Comment: Think about this like `unknown = unknown`? Or `Infinity = Infinity`? `NULL` is rather concept not specific value

Comment: Yeah, that is the final question, I supposed that null = null always is true, almost in all language i used. but i understand this for SQL, I can't compare null with null because SQL compare the concept and not the value,right?

Comment: The point is that `NULL` is SQL has to meaning 1) missing value 2) unknown value. So `UNKNOWN` = `UNKNOWN` cannot be true, at least not always.

Comment: @lad2025 Ok, perfect,  It's clear for my now.. thanks for your time and  share your knowledge ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1) First question about difference *IS NULL vs = NULL*:

Comparison operators like (`=, <>, <, >, ...`) with `NULL` always produce `NULL`.
Use `IS NULL/IS NOT NULL` instead.

2) Second question *"why (null = null) is false"*:

From [SQL and the Snare of Three-Valued Logic](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-and-the-snare-of-three-valued-logic/):

> One kind of NULL marks values which are:
>
> **missing because the value is
>   unknown**
>
> and the other kind marks values that are missing because the
>   **attribute is missing**.

When you try to compare `NULL` you actualy do something like

```
UNKNOWN = UNKNOWN
```

This is of course unknown.

Comment: Unknown=unknown isn't false, it's unknown.

Comment: No, it's treated like unknown, which only looks like it's treated as false in the trivial cases. If it were consistently treated as false inside `WHERE` clauses, then `SELECT 1 WHERE NOT (NULL = NULL)` would return 1. In fact, it returns nothing.